# Simulate analogue steering wheel input from third party software like xPadder

Tags: controllers, windows

I currently have a steering wheel connected to my htpc, running Windows 8. Since it doesn't work with (or get recognized by) all the games I play, I use xpadder.

As far as I understand, it simply presses the associated arrow key when I turn the wheel.

What I would like is a software to simulate more frequent key presses of the arrow keys the more I turn the wheel.

Example:

Tilting a little -> 100 presses / second

Tilting more -> 200 presses / second

Tilting max -> Hold down key

Right now what i currently have to do with the wheel is constantly shaking it a bit right when I just want to turn a little bit right, and so on.

Comment: Ideally, what you'd want is for the steering wheel to be recognized as an analog "axis" and then map that axis to "steering" within the game.  Not really sure the best way to do that, though.  Does windows recognize the wheel's directions as an analog axis without xpadder?

Comment: Yup xpadder recognizes it as analog, that's why i thought it could send some "fake" analog input to dirt3. ;)

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that Dirt3 doesn't allow you to bind steering to an analog axis already - that seems like a pretty straightforward/required feature for a driving game, tbh.

Comment: The feature is probably there. However none of the buttons / axises, get recignised by Dirt3. This is probably a driver related issue. There are no oficiall drivers to my cheep wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern PC games often rely on XInput (the Xbox 360 controller driver) instead of DirectInput (the every other controller in existence driver). If your wheel is DirectInput and the game only supports XInput, you can use [x360ce](http://code.google.com/p/x360ce/) to emulate a 360 controller.